# how to add index in laravel blade html attribute while calling collection

Tags: php, laravel

I am calling categories collection from controller and displaying in the blade in foreach loops

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
         <a class="a.toggle-vis" data-column="1">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I need to add index numbers generated in the loop from 1 in data-column value

```
data-column="1"
data-column="2"
data-column="3"
```

so on....in

Comment: do you mean auto increment value  such as $i++ ?

Comment: yes. i need data-column="" needs to be incremental, considering the 2 foreach loop outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing this you need to make a variable for counting after that you should pass that variable to view like below.

I am inside a method

```
public function getSingle($slug){
        $category= Post::where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
        if ($post != null) {
            $counter = 0;
            return view('blog.single')->withCategories($category)->withCounter($counter);

        } else {
            return view('error.error404');
    }

 }
```

After that you should access that **Counter** variable in view like below

```
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
      @foreach ($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
         <a class="a.toggle-vis" data-column="{{$counter++}}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a>
      @endforeach
   @endforeach
```

Comment: great man. Always you will think in your own way to find out the solution. Coding is heart-related. It needs to feel

Answer (score 0):

The classic for will do

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($category->subcategories); $i++)
       <a class="a.toggle-vis" data-column="{{$i}}">{{ $category->subcategories[$i]->name }}</a>
    @endfor
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

For a shorter one, I think, we can do something like this. A little bit dirty in view but in the small snippet, it should be okay.

```
{{ !($index = 1) }}
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
         <a class="a.toggle-vis" data-column="{{ $index++ }}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple solution (Laravel method):

```
$loop->iteration    The current loop iteration (starts at 1).
```

It will automatically increment, in every loop iteration.
Check docs:
[The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable)